# Unable to create circular linked list

Tags: c

I am getting the following errors
main.c:12:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
12 | *head;
| ^
main.c:12:2: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘head’ [-Wimplicit-int]
12 | *head;
|  ^~~~
main.c:13:13: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘CLL’

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
   struct node;
    {
    int head, data, struct node * next;
}

*head;
void create CLL()
{
    int choice=1;
    int data;
    struct node *newnode, *temp;
   
newnode (struct node x)malloc(sizeof(structnode))
printf("Enter data");
scanf("%d", &newnode->data);

newnode -> next=0;
if(head==0)

while(choice)
{
    head=temp=newnode;

else
{
temp->next=newnode; 
temp->newnode;
}
temp->next=head;
printf("Press 1 for continue and 0 for exit:");
scanf("%d", &choice);
}
}
```

Comment: Semicolon after "struct node" looks suspicious.

Comment: Your code is riddled with syntax errors and terrible formatting.

Comment: typo in `sturct`

Comment: still unable to execute it after correcting it

Comment: Frankly, it's a mess. Problems begin on line 3

Answer (score 1):

Never do this

```
   struct node;
    {
    int head, data, struct node * next;
}
```

do this

```
struct node {
   int head;
   int data;
   struct node* next;
};
```

or this

```
struct node
{
   int head;
   int data;
   struct node* next;
};
```

By typing sloppy, you make it harder to see your errors.  In your case

```
struct node;
{
   int head, data, struct node* next;
}
```

hides multiple errors

- You stop defining the `struct node` before you get to the curly braces
- You have errors in what you thought was the struct contents (but is actually an anonymous block).
- The type of next is not defined correctly because you are defining multiple fields using a pattern that creates bugs.

Once you learn how to format code, you then will see errors in the code more easily because you will look in certain places in the consistent format for the things that are easy to forget.

If you have no idea how to format `C` code because you are a beginner, that's fine.  There are multiple ways, but you only need one.  I would suggest that you use a "pretty printer" which is a program that reads your `.c` file and outputs what it thinks the correct formatting is.  These programs can be confused when you make mistakes in the original `.c` file, but they often do a good enough job that you will find the mistakes in the output faster even with the bad result.

Comment: There are other errors below, like you are using variables (thinking you are assigning them) without actually using `=` to assign to them, you have statements that are missing semicolons `;` so they run to the next line making nonsense "compound not-really-statements", you cannot provide an `else` option to an `if` statement outside of the same block as the `if` statement (which would have been seen if you indented your code).   I would start small, cleaning up at each step.  First compile a hello world containing your struct, clean up, then the next bit, clean up, and repeat (with clean ups)